# Variables are suddenly missed in the middle of the process in Zeppelin

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

The problem is if you have run a paragraph in Zeppelin, you should have access to the parameters of the previous ran paragraph in the next paragraph (REPL). Now, I have an issue with this. Sometimes, When I run a paragraph, I will get an undefined variable error in the next paragraph. Hence, I should re-run the previous paragraph.

The question is what is the problem? What happened here?

I should have mentioned that I am using the spark in the zeppelin, but I know the problem does not come from spark, as this happens for the python interpreter too.